# jvm heap space setting

Tags: java, applet, jvm

Once i kept the deployment.properties file from current user->appdata->local low->java to windows->sun->java->Deployment to set the memory per system basis.Although it didn't worked as expected I delete this file from windows->sun->java->Deployment . Now when i am trying to open any applet application in my browser i am getting the error...UNABLE TO FIND SPECIFIED FILE under the location of windows->sun.......  What change shall i do to make it work...? Anyone please... Thanks in Advance

Comment: *SPECIFIED CONFIGURATION FILE

Comment: you should edit your own question instead of commenting

Answer (score 1):

JVM heap space should be set on a 'per applet' basis.  It can be done in the HTML.  E.G.

```
<PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx128m">
```

Or if launching the applet using JWS, by specifying the memory requirements in the launch file.

Follow the last two links of the [Applet tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) for details.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Thompson. I got it.